# Increase amount of text copied in iterm2

Tags: copy-paste, iterm

When I select text in iTerm2, the text it copies cuts off at after a certain (seemingly arbitrary) point.  I did a few tests and its usually between 800 and 1500 bytes of input.

Why is this, and how can I change the settings in iTerm2 to allow me to copy all the text I highlight?

**Note:** I don't have this problem in the default "terminal" application, just in iterm.

Comment: Check that your iTerm2 is a recent version

Comment: I'm running `Build 2.1.4`, which is the latest one listed here: https://www.iterm2.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 5):

To update buffer size of copied text, I followed below steps and worked fine.

1. Quit iterm2.
2. Open mac terminal
3. Execute below commands

   ```
   defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 QuickPasteBytesPerCall -int 1024
   defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 QuickPasteDelayBetweenCalls -float 0.01
   ```

change 1024 (in bytes) and 0.01 (delay) according to your needs.

Found from [here](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-hidden-settings.html)

Answer (score 3):

It should copy all text you have selected.  You should check under Preferences>Profiles in the Terminal tab how big your scrollback buffer is.  However it is specified in lines not bytes.

Comment: Good idea, but the scrollback buffer for my active profile is already set at 1000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off `Applications in terminal may access clipboard` in the settings. I found this information as i was researching the problem myself. This seems to be still relevant, although this question is already quiet old.

To quote the information on the site ([Source](https://evertpot.com/osx-tmux-vim-copy-paste-clipboard/)):

> This works through ANSI escape sequences, and you actually want this
>   OFF. Before today I had this setting on, which kinda worked but it
>   always truncated the clipboard, which made it completely frustrating
>   for copy-pasting larger things such as logfiles.

[image]

Comment: When I uncheck that option then nothing gets pasted at all. Have tried this repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal -> Scrollback Buffer]

At **Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal -> Scrollback Buffer**, increase your **Scrollback lines** or just check **Unlimited scrollback**.

Comment: How does this solve the problem described in the question?